# Is CardDAV and CalDAV traffic over HTTPS "secure"? (Mailbox.org, Zoho.com)

Tags: caldav, carddav

It is my understanding that email hosting companies like Mailbox.org and Zoho.com [cannot encrypt your Calendar or Contacts](https://kb.mailbox.org/en/business/security-privacy-article/encryption-of-calendar-and-address-book), and because of other contraints, are forced to use CalDAV and CardDAV.

That doesn't bother me too much, but what I'm concerned about is the transmission of this over HTTPS.  I thought everything over HTTPS was "secure" from the general ether.

1. I access their CalDAV or CardDAV services over HTTPS
2. I assume this is a trusted HTTPS connection between me and the hosting service
3. My mail client sends the password
4. Maybe they've got it encrypted on disk, maybe they don't.... but my password "unlocks" that content
5. The Calendar & Contacts are sent back to me over HTTPS (SSL)

So, in that chain, who can see what?  I get that the hosting provider can see it, but let's assume I trust the hosting company.  Then, can I trust the link from my computer to the provider?

Who am I worried about here?  My ISP?  People on my LAN?

I had been told over the last decade that we should be looking for the "S" in HTTPS.  So, is that not good enough anymore?

Comment: *"So, is that not good enough anymore?"* - nothing has changed here and I wonder why you think it has. If you want end-to-end secured communication between your client application (like a browser) and the server then you can achieve this with HTTPS. If you have additional security goals like privacy against your hosting provider then HTTPS will not provide this.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich A lot of security & privacy influencers on YouTube are drilling end-to-end encryption, but many explanations of the implementation are lacking.  I'm willing to compromise on some things, but definitely not over-the-wire/in transit.  If HTTPS for CardDAV and CalDAV is "good enough" for in-transit, then I'm willing to accept that answer.

Comment: You can't question if something is secure or not before stating secure against what? HTTPS provides, among other things, confidentiality in transit, so noone except the intended/excepted party has access to content. What the party does with the content once there, is outside of what HTTPS solves. Other than that your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Answer (score 1):

*"Good enough"* is relative. As you state:

> If HTTPS for CardDAV and CalDAV is "good enough" for in-transit, then I'm willing to accept that answer.

Your relative position is a pragmatical one: *"Security yes, but not by all means."*

---

If you continue to trust in

1. the Root CA list used by your webbrowser and the systematic of realization
2. the DNS system to always deliver the correct IP address
3. the webbrowser and its plugins to not leak any information (by purpose, by accident or by being hacked)
4. the integrity of the CalDAV hoster and its infrastructure

then the SSL/TLS-tunnel to your provider is "safe enough" for transfer of credentials and data, even unencrypted through the tunnel (as it has been in the past).

*These listed axioms contain such much risk, the amount of added risk by the current cryptographic quality of the (necessary) tunnel won't change the total risk significantly.*

But all these axioms to define the frame for your security expectations already have been broken in the past (and there are much more of these axioms...)

- The SSL/TLS-tunnel is not the real problem.
- The details of the items above got improved (i.e. improved TLS versions, DNSSEC and TSIG for more reliable DNS-requests, GDPR by the EU, ...)

If today you think, in the past you have been doing right in thrusting the security techniques to access your collaboration provider, then I don't see any reason to change that.

If now you hesitate, as you have not been aware about the listed (and unlisted) axioms and now feel uncomfortable, you should start to make things better. But the first step will not be the SSL/TLS-tunnel and cannot be solved by just inventing end-to-end encryption.

---

The path to "End-to-end encryption"

"End-to-end encryption" will reduce the risk for data leakage. Somehow its an evolutionary step similar to the one when the servers changed from storing plain passwords to storing hashed values representing just the fingerprint of the password, without the possibility of password extraction.
By doing this, the service provider had to change from *"revealing the forgotten password"* to *"providing an access token to be able to create a new password"*.

With the wide availability of software with better encryption (at lower costs), the providers will change to the better solution. But without demanding it, such software will not reach the market.

*The [article of your provider](https://kb.mailbox.org/en/business/security-privacy-article/encryption-of-calendar-and-address-book) you've linked in your question is just a reaction to this market pressure.*

Comment: Did this answer your question or is something relevant missing?